# Using PostgreSQL to hold an array of data

Tags: postgresql, database-design, enum

I am trying to use a postgreSQL data base column to store values from an array (or point to an enum table which does this).  I will get an array of data like `['one','two','five']`. The array can contain any amount of items from 0 to 10.

I have an enum table with these values:

```
id    value
1     one
2     two
3     three
4     four
5     five
```

I want my database cell to point to all of the values that are contained in the array.  Is this even possible or is there a common way to structure database tables to fix this issue.

So my desired solution when passed the array `['one','two','five']` would be to have a single cell in my database hold the enum pointers `1, 2, 5`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view on the table that joins with the enum table and shows an array of `text`.

Then create an `INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger on the view that translates the strings to numbers and stores the number array in the underlying table.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.  After reading some docs on creating views I think I understand the general idea.  I am still a bit confused about how I create the `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger.  Is part of the query that will be run by my backend each time there is an update to my array?

Comment: Yes, you will also need an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger that does the same thing whenever there is sn `UPDATE`; they could use the same trigger function. Whenever even a single array element is modified, a new version of the whole row has to be written, that's how PostgreSQL works. To avoid that, you should normalize the design.